# Deploying Qt console application with QtPlugin

Tags: c++, linux, qt5, qtplugin

**The context :**

I'm currently working on a multiplatform server-side console application using Qt.
I have a development computer (pc-dev) and a server where I want to deploy my application (pc-server).
pc-dev is configured with all the development stuff (gcc, Qt5, cmake, etc...) but the pc-server does not have all this tools.
Both runs CentOs 7.
My application uses plugins to load some files that extends it's functionality.

**My problem :**

As my console application does not use QtGui / QtWidgets modules, I don't want dependencies on them (Ok that's normal you would say)
When I compile my QtPlugin, the generated *.so file have a dependency on Qt5Gui.so (confirmed by `ldd myfile.so`), and so when I deploy my application, the loading fails, because Qt5Gui.so is missing.

I don't understand why I have this dependency because my plugin does not use gui functionnality.
It just provides methods to get a version / a filename / and some access to it.
The only file included is "QtPlugin".

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution : 
I had in the *.pro file :

```
QT          += core
TARGET      = MyPlugin
TEMPLATE    = lib
CONFIG      += plugin
```

and it seems that the "gui" module is included by default, so :

```
QT          -= gui
```

fixed the problem.